# Send message to service bus with slightly different properties based on time of day within one logic app?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

My logic app gets triggered with a Recurrence which sends a message to the Service Bus Queue.

What I am trying to do is send a different property (or body) to my service bus queue based on the time of day that the Recurrence gets triggered. Right now I am triggering the Recurrence 8 times a day.

I could do this by creating 8 logic apps, however this seems unpractical because the logic apps would be pretty much identical except for the recurrence time and the property being sent to the service bus. And if I have to scale this up to more than 8 times a day, that will be annoying having to create a new logic app each time.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use utcNow() with a custom format string that returns maybe only the hour component which you can use to determine when in the day you are.

If the exact local time is important, you can also use convertFromUtc() to get the zone local time first.